# How to add a line break in an Angular Foundation Popover content?

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation, haml

This seems like it should be a simple problem but it's turning out to be a lot more involved that I initially thought.

I have a couple of items inside my Angular Foundation Popover directive that i would like to separate with a line break.

```
.div{ 'popover' => "Name: {{ user.name }} /br Age: {{ user.age }}", 'popover-trigger' => 'click' }
```

What is the solution to adding a line break where the /br is in this line of html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite tricky. If you are using [angular-foundation](http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/) (and I realy recommand to use it), you can modify the official popover template to be HTML unsafe - than you can use HTML in popovers:

JS

```
"use strict";

// app definition - don't forget to include angular-foundation module
angular.module("app", ["mm.foundation"]);

// just o controller, nothing special
angular
  .module("app")
  .controller("MainController", MainController);

  function MainController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.name = "John Doe"
    vm.email = "john.doe@example.com"
  }

// unsafe filter - this is used in the template below
angular
  .module("app")
  .filter("unsafe", unsafe)

  function unsafe($sce) {
    return function (val) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
  };

// oficial popover template modification
angular
  .module("template/popover/popover.html", [])
  .run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put("template/popover/popover.html",
      "<div class=\"joyride-tip-guide\" ng-class=\"{ in: isOpen(), fade: animation() }\">\n" +
      "  <span class=\"joyride-nub\" ng-class=\"{\n" +
      "    bottom: placement === 'top',\n" +
      "    left: placement === 'right',\n" +
      "    right: placement === 'left',\n" +
      "    top: placement === 'bottom'\n" +
      "  }\"></span>\n" +
      "  <div class=\"joyride-content-wrapper\">\n" +
      "    <h4 ng-bind-html=\"title | unsafe\" ng-show=\"title\"></h4>\n" +
      "    <p ng-bind-html=\"content | unsafe\"></p>\n" +
      "  </div>\n" +
      "</div>\n" +
      "");
}]);
```

HTML

```
<main ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as vm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 column">
      <div popover="{{vm.name + '<br />' + vm.email}}" popover-trigger="mouseenter">
        <h1>Hover me!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Here you are working [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/Akarienta/pen/gpXGzp/).

You can also make your own directive to have both HTML safe popovers and HTML unsafe popovers - or you can use [tooltip](http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/#tooltip) insetead which has support for HTML unsafe by default (directive `tooltip-html-unsafe`).

Comment: interesting! I guess that's one solution. The only problem with this is that you would have to do this over and over again each time you update angular-foundation. I wonder if there's a simpler, more permanent, solution? If I don't hear of another in a couple of days I'll use yours as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @JDC You don't have to modify the library itself so there is no need to modify angular-foundation with every update. You can simply place the modification into your own file - it overwrites the original template :-)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using your code. Specifically, for those who  may need the solution in the future, I used the code blocks under the "unsafe filter" and "official popover template modification" in Akarienta's JS file.  You just need to include it in any of your angular files.  Be sure to change the .module("app") "app" to whatever you are using for the ng-app.  Also, you want to be sure that your file is in your assets pipeline AFTER the mm.foundation loads so that this modification code can override the original.